# check textfield value, if equal to given value then action if not then do nothing

Tags: jquery

What I want is when the textfield **#ItemAddress** on focus, check another textfield #**CAT_Custom_279176** and if the value of which carried equals "**SG**", then clear the value of textfield #**CAT_Custom_269379** and #**CAT_Custom_248591**; if value is not "SG" then do nothing. The below code is not correct, please help... Many Thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript">// if Singapore
      $(function() {
      $('#ItemAddress').focus(function() {
          if ($('#CAT_Custom_279176').val('SG')) {
              $('#CAT_Custom_269379').val(''); // clear value in state field
              $('#CAT_Custom_248591').val(''); // clear value in city field
          }
      });
      })               
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong. You are setting the value to SG, not comparing anything.

```
$('#CAT_Custom_279176').val('SG')) {
```

It should be

```
$('#CAT_Custom_279176').val() == 'SG') {
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing `#CAT_Custom_279176` value

```
  <script type="text/javascript">// if Singapore
      $(function() {
      $('#ItemAddress').focus(function() {
          if ($('#CAT_Custom_279176').val() == 'SG') {
              $('#CAT_Custom_269379').val(''); // clear value in state field
              $('#CAT_Custom_248591').val(''); // clear value in city field
          }
      });
      })               
  </script>
```